# Dynamically loading XAML Controls is slow?

Tags: performance, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm creating dynamic controls (buttons, scroll viewers, etc.) via Code Behind. I have a lot of processing done here (a lot of ViewModels processed, and what goes into each of the button), and I notice that every time I dynamically load the controls, it seems to be slow.

Is there any way to improve the performance so lower spec computers can better handle it?

Thank you

Comment: Don't create controls in code-behind. XAML is there for a reason. Embrace it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using XAML and binding ViewModels but I guess maybe it's just loading lots of XAML controls.